# How do third-party ETF websites know the holdings of ETFs at any given time?

Tags: etf, online-data-source

Fund management companies' (e.g. Vanguard, BlackRock iShares, etc.) annual reports include a complete list of securities held by each ETF. This complete list is only published in annual or semi-annual reports, so the data is likely outdated as soon as the report is published. I noticed that there are several third-party websites that list the holdings of ETFs. How do the websites know each ETF's holdings at any given time? Do they have some kind of special arrangement with the fund management companies to obtain the data?

Comment: Do you _know_ that the 3rd-party sites are showing anything other than what was in the last published report?

Comment: Some of the sites provide information how recent the data is. I guess everyone can buy the information from the indexing company

Answer (score 2):

The premise of the question does not appear to be true. Here's an iShares webpage for the EEM ETF that shows the complete list of holdings as of the previous trading day:

https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239637/ishares-msci-emerging-markets-etf

Comment: This appears to vary by region. For example, both Vanguard UK and iShares UK show less information than Vanguard US and iShares US. In the US version, they provide the list of all holdings along with the exact number of shares of each holding. In the UK version, they don't publish the exact number of shares of each holding.

Comment: "Here's an iShares webpage for the EEM ETF that shows the complete list of holdings as of the previous trading day: ..." — No, that is a list of holdings from last Friday (2021-07-09, i.e. four days ago).

Comment: @Flux isn't that saying the same thing? Today is Monday 12 July; the last trading day was Friday 9 July. I pulled up an archive copy from a Tuesday and the data given was from Monday so it seems to be a "most recent available" thing.